# Getting different 2 audio in the same headphone or headset

Tags: audio, ubuntu

I want to get my headphone to play totally different audio in each ear of it. I mean: `audio_1.mp3` being played in the right ear - and - `audio_2.mp3` in the left ear >> from the same device (eg: my laptop). Is that possible? If so, Is there any software for that for Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Hi ibrahem.  It *is* definitely possible!  I have done this manually by creating a single audio file with completely different sources for each channel.  Hopefully someone here will know of a software solution to do it automatically for you.  Out of curiosity, what is your application of playing different files in different channels?

Comment: @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket♦ ==> me and my brother use the same laptop : I split the screen to 2 areas and each of us make his programs appear onTop of screen in his area  , also there is a keyboard connected to a USB port , and for mouse cursor, I wrote a python script using PyQt5 and PyAutoGUI to make another cursor (gui) appear on top of screen , and it can be moved using arrow keys when Alt is pressed , left click is made using Backspace+Left ...etc ,,,,,,,,,,,, this is all to make the labtop be used by two persons at the same time, there are still many interrupts but it is fine

Comment: You are a genius!  That's wonderfully creative and an incredible use of resources.